# importing google/protobuf/*.protos when using protoc-c

Tags: protocol-buffers

I installed protoc, protoc-c, libprotobuf and libprotobuf-c on my system. I have .proto file that imports timestamp.proto as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message DeviceCtx {

    google.protobuf.Timestamp CID = 1;

    uint32 ContextLen = 2;

    bytes ContextBuf = 3;

}
```

Am using protoc-c to generate the C binding for the same using below:

```
home>protoc-c --c_out=. a.proto
home>ls a.pb-c*
a.pb-c.c a.pb-c.h
```

It generates the C bindings for this proto file. But when I try compiling this .c file, I get the following error as it is looking for timestamp.pb-c.h file.

```
home>gcc a.pb-c.c dummy.c -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf-c
In file included from a.pb-c.c:9:0:
a.pb-c.h:17:10: fatal error: google/protobuf/timestamp.pb-c.h: No such file or directory
#include "google/protobuf/timestamp.pb-c.h"
^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

With protoc-c I don't see the header files for standard proto like timestamp.proto being generated/staged when I installed the protoc-c. Does that mean we have to explicitly recompile all the protos under google/protobuf using protoc-c to generate the C binding for all the protos (google/protobuf/*.protos), stage the generated header files under /usr/local/include/google/protobuf and include *pb-c.c files in our library make for it to build successfully? Do I need to install any specific package to get the C bindings for protos under google/protobuf. Did I miss some step during install, which would have done the autogeneration of C bindings for all protos under google/protobuf and staged it correctly.

I don't see any issues if I don't import any protos from google/protobuf.

When using protoc for the same proto file, I don't see any such issue.

```
home>protoc --cpp_out=. a.proto
home>g++ a.pb.cc dummy.cc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lprotobuf
home>
```

I am new to protobuf and using protoc-c compiler for the first time. So apologize for my shortcomings.

Thanks,
-Mini

Answer (score 0):

Usually in 3rd party protobuf libraries, you would treat the Google's `.proto` files the same as you would any `.proto` you write yourself. So you would write rules to compile them to a folder in your project-specific include directory.